# database connection string in enterprise architect eap file

Tags: odbc, connection-string, enterprise-architect

In earlier versions of Enterprise Architect (ex. 9.2) I had possibility to run project stored in database using connection string stored in eap file. It was possible to define database connection and I needn't to define ODBC DSN in system settings (it was proceeded automatically). In new EA (version 13) previously configured eap file with link to db repository does not work. There is message box: "The selected ODBC DSN '' can not be found". When I put DSN name to connection string definition in eap file this link starts working. But previous version of EA worked without need to define DSN in Windows settings and it was quite useful.

My connection string in EAP file looks like this:

```
EAConnectString:CCC:ea_gr12 --- DBType=4;Connect=Provider=MSDASQL.1;DRIVER=PostgreSQL Unicode;DATABASE=ea_gr12;SERVER=server.name;PORT=5432;UID=ea;PWD=ea;
```

And it does not work (in previous EA version it worked)

Am I doing something wrong or this functionality (connection string without defining DSN in system settings) disappeared from EA

Comment: I just tested with an ODBC connection and had no issue. Check the ODBC strings: File/Open > Edit Connection String and see if something got clobbered.